# Select records where except A or B

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause, records, except

I am having trouble converting the following human language to MySQL query:

```
Select all rows except those with ColA equals '1' OR ColB equals '1'.
```

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ColA = '1' OR ColB = '1';
```

The above will pull records that matches the where clause above (either ColA = '1' or ColB = '1'), but how do I get the results opposite of that? I hope I am describing it correctly. Please let me know if it is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
    *
from
    `myTable`
where
    `colA` <> 1 and
    `ColB` <> 1
```

This will work for you only if the `colA` and `colB` are `NOT NULL`. If there are rows with `colA = NULL` or `colB = NULL` you have to change the condition in your request.

```
select
    *
from
    `myTable`
where
    (`colA` <> 1 or `colA` is null) and 
    (`colB` <> 1 or `colB` is null)
```

Of course it depends on if you want the rows with `NULL` values, but many people forget about this.

Here is SQL Fiddle example http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea797/2

Comment: Thank you! This worked! It was the null values throwing me off. I  have mixed values with both null and empty. The solution others gave work, but they forgot about the null/empty values.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE ColA <> '1'
AND ColB <> '1'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE NOT (ColA = '1' OR ColB = '1')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ColA <> '1' && ColB <> '1';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ColA <> 1 AND ColB <> 1;
```

or if you want amplify the list (1, 2, 3) instead of only (1), try:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ColA NOT IN (1,2,3) AND ColB NOT IN (1,2,3);
```